# How to split xxxx table rows into arrays of 100 each using jquery and account for rounding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slice

I'm trying to paginate a table using jquery.

I want to split xxxx number of rows into arrays of 100 rows each, which I can then run through to populate the subpages I'm creating.

currently I'm trying this:

```
 var rowsPerPageS = 100,
     maxRows = table.find( "tbody tr, TBODY TR" ).length,
     splitRows = [];

 // split table array into array of 100
 for( i = 0; i < Math.round(maxRows/rowsPerPageS); i++){
    splitRows.push( $( table ).find( "tbody tr, TBODY TR" ).slice( rowsPerPage*i,rowsPerPageS*(i+1) ) )
     }
```

The above seems to work well for 100,200,300,400 etc rows, which will give me 1,2,3,4 objects in my array. But if I have 333 rows for example, 333/100 = 3.33 = 3 objects and I'm "dropping" the last 33 rows.

**Questions:**
how can I account for number of "uneven" number of rows? If I add +1 to the number of loops I will be getting an empty object if rows are 100,200,300 or <99, so this is not possible.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I want to split xxxx number of rows into arrays of 100 rows each"*

Give this a shot...

```
var rowsPerPageS = 100,
    splitRows = [],
    rows = $( table ).find( "tbody tr" ).toArray();

for( i = 0; i < rows.length; i += rowsPerPageS ){
    splitRows.push( rows.slice(i, i + rowsPerPageS ) );
}
```

---

You can get rid of `.toArray()` if you actually wanted jQuery objects.

Comment: but if I have 234 rows, won't this create 234 iterations of the for loop? also I will need to loop through the objects/arrays in the next step to populate subpage tables, so I'm not sure whether to have objects or arrays. What's better to run-through?

Comment: @frequent: No, it's incrementing by the value of `rowsPerPagsS`, as in `i += rowsPerPageS`. So `i` is `0`, `100`, `200`, etc...

Comment: Regarding your updated comment, it depends on what you want to  do with them. If you're calling jQuery methods, then you might as well have them ready as jQuery objects. Is there a reason you couldn't just do the work from the next step directly in this `for` loop?

Comment: hm. haven't thought about that yet. i will have to setup a nested jquery-mobiles page each containing a table with the respective rows. For now I'm happy I have the table split correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.ceil() instead of Math.round(). Ceil rounds a number upwards to the nearest integer, while round to nearest. For example

```
Math.round(0.4) => 0
Math.ceil(0.1) => 1
Math.ceil(1) => 1
```